# I am creating a image editing ui using tkinter but I am not able to zoom the cropped image. I have given my code below

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

```
def zoom_cropped_image(self):
        if self.crop_mode_active and self.original_image and self.displayed_image:
            self.undo_stack.append(copy.deepcopy(self.displayed_image))
            self.apply_zoom_to_cropped_image()
            self.image_changed = True  # Image has been modified
            self.display_images()

def apply_zoom_to_cropped_image(self):
# Get the original cropped region
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = self.cropped_region

# Calculate the center of the cropped region
    center_x = (x1 + x2) / 2
    center_y = (y1 + y2) / 2

# Apply zoom factor to the width and height of the cropped region
    new_width = (x2 - x1) * self.zoom_factor
    new_height = (y2 - y1) * self.zoom_factor

# Calculate new coordinates for the cropped region
    x1_zoomed = max(center_x - new_width / 2, 0)
    y1_zoomed = max(center_y - new_height / 2, 0)
    x2_zoomed = min(center_x + new_width / 2, self.original_image.width)
    y2_zoomed = min(center_y + new_height / 2, self.original_image.height)

    cropped_image = self.original_image.crop((x1_zoomed, y1_zoomed, x2_zoomed, y2_zoomed))
    self.displayed_image = Image.new("RGB", (int(new_width), int(new_height)), color=(255, 255, 255))
    self.displayed_image.paste(cropped_image, (int((new_width - (x2_zoomed - x1_zoomed)) / 2), int((new_height - (y2_zoomed - y1_zoomed)) / 2)))

    # Update the cropped region
    self.cropped_region = (x1_zoomed, y1_zoomed, x2_zoomed, y2_zoomed)
```

I have tried zooming the cropped image but the cropped image is not getting zoomed.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Zoomed coordinates needs within the bounds of the original image.

The pasting of the cropped image need to adjust into the displayed image.

Try this:

```
def apply_zoom_to_cropped_image(self):
  # Get the original cropped region
  x1, y1, x2, y2 = self.cropped_region

  # Calculate the center of the cropped region
  center_x = (x1 + x2) / 2
  center_y = (y1 + y2) / 2

  # Apply zoom factor to the width and height of the cropped region
  new_width = (x2 - x1) * self.zoom_factor
  new_height = (y2 - y1) * self.zoom_factor

  # Calculate new coordinates for the cropped region
  x1_zoomed = max(center_x - new_width / 2, 0)
  y1_zoomed = max(center_y - new_height / 2, 0)
  x2_zoomed = min(center_x + new_width / 2, self.original_image.width)
  y2_zoomed = min(center_y + new_height / 2, self.original_image.height)

  # Ensure the zoomed coordinates are within bounds
  x1_zoomed = max(0, min(x1_zoomed, self.original_image.width - new_width))
  y1_zoomed = max(0, min(y1_zoomed, self.original_image.height - new_height))
  x2_zoomed = x1_zoomed + new_width
  y2_zoomed = y1_zoomed + new_height

  cropped_image = self.original_image.crop((x1_zoomed, y1_zoomed, x2_zoomed, y2_zoomed))
  self.displayed_image = Image.new("RGB", (int(new_width), int(new_height)), color=(255, 255, 255))
  self.displayed_image.paste(cropped_image, (0, 0))  # Paste at the top-left corner

  # Update the cropped region
  self.cropped_region = (x1_zoomed, y1_zoomed, x2_zoomed, y2_zoomed)
```